# How do you fix scaling issues with MPLABXIDE (with MCC) in Windows 10 when using a HiDef display?

Tags: mplab

MPLAB X IDE (Ver 5.30) starts scaled to a proper resolution reflecting the scaling settings in Windows; but, when the MCC plugin is started it results in the refresh of the Window and the window shrinking back to 100% scaling with MCC parts alone scaled to the system settings. This makes the IDE unusable on those displays.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing this is a multi step process.

Set the underlying Netbeans  IDE to be DPI aware, by adding `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true` to end of the `default_options` line in mplab config file at  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v5.xx\mplab_platform\etc\mplab_ide.conf`.

Then change the system settings for scaling MPLAB to be correct

1. Right click on MPLAB icon on desktop.
2. Choose `Properties`.
3. Go to `Compatibility` tab.
4. Click on the `Change high DPI settings` button
5. Tick `Overide high DPI scaling` and choose `System` or `System (Enhanced)` in the dropbox.
6. Click `OK` then `Apply`

This worked on Windows 10 19.05 on a Surface Book